# setPresence activity type in discord.js v14 can only be set to "PLAYING"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

When I try to set the status of the bot, I do not know the type, basically, there are 4 ways: `PLAYING`, `WATCHING`, `LISTENING`, and `STREAMING`. But I can't set anything else, I can only use the default `PLAYING`.

Am I inattentive or can't really be like that in the newer update?

```
client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: `discord.js v14`, type: `WATCHING` }], status: 'dnd' })
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, I think you might have to use the [ActivityType](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType) enum. [PresenceData](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/PresenceData) -> Array<[ActivitiesOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/ActivitiesOptions)> -> type: [ActivityType](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In v14, you will need to use the [`ActivityType` enums](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType) or numbers.

You can import it from `discord.js`:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
```

And use it like this:

```js
client.user.setPresence({
  activities: [{ name: `discord.js v14`, type: ActivityType.Watching }],
  status: 'dnd',
});
```

List of `ActivityType`s:

| v13 | v14 | v14 value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `"COMPETING"` | `ActivityType.Competing` | `5` |
| `"CUSTOM"` | `ActivityType.Custom` | `4` |
| `"LISTENING"` | `ActivityType.Listening` | `2` |
| `"PLAYING"` | `ActivityType.Playing` | `0` |
| `"STREAMING"` | `ActivityType.Streaming` | `1` |
| `"WATCHING"` | `ActivityType.Watching` | `3` |

Comment: I'd try to do it with subcommand, but even if I convert the type variable to a string, it doesn't work if I write it after ActivityType. :

const type = interaction.options.getString('type')
            client.user.setPresence({
                activities: [{ name: name, type: ActivityType.type }] });

Comment: Is this similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037611/select-menu-status-discord-js-v14)? Then I would use `ActivityTypes` as the `value` of the options. E.g. ```{ label: `Competing`, description: `Competing`,  value: ActivityTypes.Competing }, { label: `Watching`, description: `Watching`,  value: ActivityTypes.Watching }``` etc. and then `getString('type')` will be the correct value so you could use it like this: `client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name, type }] });`. At least, I think so :)

Comment: yes, it's similar, but I didn't do it that way because it takes a name, and it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Not sure if I can understand what's wrong with that name

Comment: So I'm going to do the type in a select menu?

Comment: And how do I attach the status name to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246608/discussion-between-zsolt-meszaros-and-plshelpme).