# how do i change my discord.js bots status to streaming?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

this is my code

```
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity('My Hero Academia', ({type: "WATCHING"}))
})
```

does anyone know how to make it streaming?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setPresence activity type in discord.js v14 can only be set to "PLAYING"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049373/setpresence-activity-type-in-discord-js-v14-can-only-be-set-to-playing)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ActivityOptions` object (the second parameter of `setActivity()`), just change the type to `ActivityType.Streaming` (make sure to import the discord.js object `ActivityType`), and add another property `url`, which you set to the url of the stream, like a Twitch stream. For example:

```
// somewhere at the top of your code
const { ActivityType } = require("discord.js");

// where you set the activity
client.user.setActivity({
    name: "My Hero Academia",
    type: ActivityType.Streaming,
    url: "https://twitch.tv/twitch_user",
});
```

Note that you must have the url property in the setActivity options object.

Edit: Thanks to Zsolt Meszaros in the comments, in discord.js v14 [you must use enums everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14/73028855#73028855), for example, `ActivityType.Streaming`

Comment: _"I'm not even sure why you need to use the `ActivityType.Streaming` object[...]"_ In discord.js v14, strings no longer work and you have to [use enums everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028855/6126373)

Comment: Oh I see, I haven't used v14 much yet so thanks for the info