# setActivity will only set the activity type to "Playing". Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

When trying to set the activity status of the bot I only manage to set have it say "Playing x".

Looking at the documentation of discord.js the correct usage should be:

```
client.user.setActivity('discord.js', { type: ActivityType.Watching });
```

But even when trying this usage I get the same result of it displaying "Playing discord.js".

This is my code currently:

```
const ActivityType = require('discord.js');

client.user.setActivity('/play', { type: ActivityType.Listening });
```

But I have also tried

```
client.user.setActivity({ name: '/play', type: ActivityType.Listening });
```

The client is being passed from my index file, I get no errors. Also tried the example from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049373/setpresence-activity-type-in-discord-js-v14-can-only-be-set-to-playing), also giving me the same result.

What am I missing here?

Edit.
Full code is:

**ready.js**

```
const ActivityType = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'ready',
  once: true,
  execute(client) {
    client.user.setActivity({ name: '/play', type: ActivityType.Listening });
  },
};
```

**index.js**

```
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your import:  `$const ActivityType = require('discord.js');`

swtich to: `$const { ActivityType } = require('discord.js');`

because discord changed the documentation

```
const { ActivityType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'ready',
  once: true,
  execute(client) {
    client.user.setActivity({ name: '/play', type: ActivityType.Listening });
  },
};
```

Comment: hi, please could you provide an explanation for future readers?