# Discord.js v14 doesn't show the status

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been trying for hours in vain to give my testbot its own status, I just can't find a solution why this doesn't work. I'm quite new in the topic Discord.js, so if someone has a solution or finds errors here please report back :)

I have tried to set the status with setActivity and setPresence and the corresponding parameters but both without success.
I created a second bot and again the bot did not show any status.

```
const {BOT_TOKEN}=require("./config.json");
const {Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Collection} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on("ready", async () => {
    try {
        await client.user.setPresence({
            status: 'online',
            activity: {
                name: 'Test',
                type: 'PLAYING'
            }
        });
        console.log(`Bot's Status: successfully updated`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Bot's Status: error while updating status")
    }

    //client.user.setStatus("online");

    console.log(`Bot's current status: ${client.user.presence.status}`);
    console.log(`Login process as: ${client.user.tag} was successful`);
});

client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: You should add the `GuildPresences` intent. Also, does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049373/setpresence-activity-type-in-discord-js-v14-can-only-be-set-to-playing/73050109#73050109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `activities` and not `activity` ([Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-set-both-status-and-activity-in-one-go))

Comment: thanks that was the error i was looking for and thanks for the direct link to the setPresence part in the guide :)